# Open subset of compact-open topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $X$ a locally-compact metric space, equip $C(X,E)$ with the compact-open topology.  Let $F:E \rightarrow E$ and consider the induced map $F_{\star}(f):=F \circ f$ on $C(X,E)$.  When is $F_{\star}$ open?

*Update*
More generally, what is an example of an open mapping $G:C(X,E)\to C(X,E)$ which is not a homeomorphism (possibly not continuous)?

*Update:  I think this should work, but, I feel that something is wrong with the argument...*

Let $F:E\rightarrow E$ be open and admit a continuous-left inverse.  For every compact $K\subseteq X$ and over open $U\subseteq E$ (both non-empty) we know that $\{f\in C(X,E):f(K)\subseteq U\}$ is a basic open subset of $C(X,E)$ for this topology.  Then
$$
F_{\star}(\{f\in C(X,E):f(K)\subseteq U\})= 
\{g \in C(X,E): (\exists f \in C(X,E))\, g=F\circ f \mbox{ and } 
g(K)\subseteq F(U)\}
=
\{g \in C(X,E): g(K)\subseteq F(U)\}
,
$$
but since $F$ is open then $F(U)$ is open.  Hence, $F_{\star}(\{f\in C(X,E):f(K)\subseteq U\})$ is a basic open subset of $C(X,E)$ for this topology.

Comment: Do you mean $\exists g \in C(X, E), f = F \circ g$ ?

Comment: Oops, yes indeed (or else this would be a wildly different question, with unclear reference to g).  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For $X = \mathbb R$, the constant function equal to 1 is in your set but its hard to believe that there is a neighborhood around it of functions bounded by $1$.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Right.  I focused the question then to only the generalized (second part); i.e.: when is post-composition with $F$ open?

Comment: Why is every continuous function $g$ with $g(K) \subseteq F(U)$ a composition $g = F \circ f$ with $f$ *continuous*?  In particular, I don't see why we can solve $g = F \circ f$ even on $K$ (with $f$ continuous); but, if that's not an issue, what if $g(K) \subseteq F(U)$ but not $g(X) \subseteq F(X)$?

Comment: Right, so then we need $F$ admit a continuous left-inverse + F be open?

Comment: If $X$ is compact you can apply tensor product techniques because $C(X,E)=C(X)\tilde\otimes_\varepsilon E$. See the book of Defant and Floret section 4.4.: Whenever $F:E\to G$ is a metric surjection (i.e., $G$ is a quotient of $E$ and has the quotient norm) then $id \tilde\otimes_\varepsilon: C(X,E)\to C(X,G)$ is also a metric surjection.